# React Native pass params through tabs.screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

how can I pass params or an object to a Tabs-Screen when clicking on that tab in React Nativ? This is the code of a bottom Tab Navigation on one page of the app.

```
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MainContainer({ route, navigation  }) {

    
//function MainContainer({  }) {
    
  // Load the icon font before using it
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({ IcoMoon: require('../../assets/icomoon/zepra_icons.ttf') });
  const { data }    = route.params;
    
    console.log('data:');
    console.log(data);
    
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }
    
  return (
      <Tab.Navigator
                initialRouteName={projectsName}
                screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                  headerShown: false,
                  tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                    let iconName;
                    let rn = route.name;

                    if (rn === projectsName) {
                      iconName = focused ? 'PROJEKTE_ALLE' : 'PROJEKTE_ALLE';
                    } else if (rn === waermeschutzName) {
                      iconName = focused ? 'HAUS_3' : 'HAUS_3';
                    } else if (rn === begehungenName) {
                      iconName = focused ? 'NOTIZ_ERSTELLEN' : 'NOTIZ_ERSTELLEN';
                    }

                    return <Icon name={iconName} size={43} color={color} />;
                  },
                  'tabBarActiveTintColor': '#4283b1',
                  'tabBarInactiveTintColor': '#5db8bd',
                  'tabBarStyle':{ 'paddingTop':4, 'height':90 },
                  'tabBarLabelStyle':{ 'paddingTop':3, 'fontSize':13 }
                })}>
                <Tab.Screen name={projectsName} component={ProjectsScreen} /> 
                <Tab.Screen name={waermeschutzName} component={WaermeschutzScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name={begehungenName} component={BegehungenScreen} />
                    
      </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default MainContainer;
```

I have tryed several ways but could not get it to work. Does anyone have a working example or cane someone help me with my code??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [initialParams prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/) for the `Tab.Screen` components in order to pass the initial params to each tab.

Here is an example on how to do this for your first tab screen.

```js
<Tab.Screen name={projectsName} component={ProjectsScreen} initialParams={{ data }} />
```